# rails helper select_month option to not show all months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a report were I need to provide users a select that allows them to choose the current month or the next two months.

I discovered the rails helper **select_month** which works great if you want a list of all months. Is there any way to specify the months to display using select_month or I assume its might be better to create my own helper for this?

For example I can get the ranges I want based on date using date helpers as shown below and build a select but I thought perhaps there is a cleaner way to do this with select_month.

> **get current month date range manually**  <%=Date.today.beginning_of_month%>,<%=Date.today.end_of_month%>
>
> **get next month date range manually**  <%=Date.today.beginning_of_month +
>   1.months%>,<%=n_month.end_of_month%>
>
> **get second month date range manually on current date** <%=Date.today.beginning_of_month +
>   2.months%>,<%=month_after_next.end_of_month%>

So far I can only see ways to modify the date label display, select name and values for all months with select_month.

**Just displays all months**
`select_month(Date.today`)

Answer (score 1):

After some research it looks like you cannot specify a month range with **select_month** helper. If I'm wrong input is welcome. Instead I utilized **select_tag** and a date range which worked for my needs. Being new to rails I keep discovering so many new ways to do things.

if you just want a drop down with months and the month number you can easily do this with a range like so:

```
<%= select_tag(:selmonth, options_for_select((Date.today.month..Date.today.month + 2).map {|m| [Date::MONTHNAMES[m], m]})) %>
```

**will return**

```
<select name="selmonth" id="selmonth">
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">Sept</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
</select>
```

I, however wanted the value as the first date of that month. Ruby and rails offer a lot of flexibility. Probably an even better way to do this but it works for me.

```
<%= select_tag(:selmonth, options_for_select((Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.beginning_of_month + 2.months).map{|d| [d.beginning_of_month.strftime("%B"), d.beginning_of_month.strftime("%F")]}.uniq)) %>
```

**will return**

```
<select name="selmonth" id="selmonth">
  <option value="2015-08-01">August</option>
  <option value="2015-09-01">September</option>
  <option value="2015-10-01">October</option>
</select>
```